What would be an effective way to gather client feedback?
Recently, I had some problems with my client. They give me so much feedback for the poster, and then the other one on their team give other feedback. So they send me several emails for just one poster. Do you guys have any process for working with the clients like that.

Communicate with the client these struggles / desires!

I often ask clients to gather their thoughts and send a single email with desired revisions - as explained, in an effort to minimize the time needed to make alterations, thus saving them money.
In reality, it forces the client to be more organized on their end. While it's true that a single collective email for alterations does make them easier to implement. The reality is, it also makes my job so much easier if I don't have to sort through multiple emails - especially from separate people - which can, and will, conflict at times.
A single point of contact for alterations helps. Even if the client is reviewing pieces "by committee".
Essentially I respond with "You all sort things out and let me know what you decide." type of reply, but worded more professionally.

I wish I could upvote for each paragraph. Rule of thumb - one client, one channell. let it be a designed person or commitee. Also One request (list in e-mail) - one reply.

I wanted to comment and ended up with answer...
Scott's answer is great and I'm only expanding his.
Disclaimer:

capitalized 'You' means You personally.
'you' means You and Your client.


Tell Your client You are struggling with their inputs. There is no way they can notice how seriously they are interfering with Your work. There is very slim chance the (n+1)-th email does not contradict n previous e-mails. For n = 2 the chances are low and for higher ns it only decreases. The sooner you communicate it, the better. For You and for them too.
Propose different workflow and stick to it.

Decide one person to communicate with You. Be it head of a commitee, group leader, whatever.
This person will collect all inputs from their commitee/team and send one e-mail with all requests. (While collecting it they will also sort conflicts)
You will assign the requests to Your team (You can be a team of one) and solve them.
You send them Your work and GoTo >2.2.
Cycle until both sides - Your team and client's commitee/team - are satisfied.


Stick to the proposed and agreed workflow with no exceptions.
With next client(s) agree on such workflow before signing the contract.

You can tell them that from now on, any e-mail, except for the communicating ONE, will be automatically forwarded to spam folder and ignored. Then ignore those e-mails. Or forward them to the commitee head and ask them to sort it out.
Another point is that you need to set "do not disturb" policies too. There are three modes:

Requests definitions
Discussion
Your work on requests

These stages must not merge, otherwise a lot of work gets wasted.
Send Your work and switch to mode 1, where all work is on their side and You can work on anything else. When they are done then you discuss next step and agree on new set of requests. When the discussion ends and all requests are sent, switch to mode 3 where you ignore all inputs until you are either done, or need more details.
This strict isolation will prevent them from interfering with your work - imagine working on a logo, agreeed that it will be once-colour vector graphics and in the middle of the work you get request to incorporate image...

Client management is its own particular skill. Sometimes the client has too many chefs in the kitchen. It might be helpful to have the client sort out their hierarchy of input so that you don't have to be an HR consultant for them. That way the designer can work more effectively and not waste time if the client's input comes from one person. It's not good use of design time to sort out a client's mess.

Hey Tim and welcome. I tried to improve your answer's clarity. While this is a good sentiment, this answer lacks any details of how to do this, which is precisely the point of the question
